# Why can't some images be loaded on Firefox?

Tags: image, ubuntu, firefox, repository, filenames

I pushed some images to Github where some of them have the string "google-analytics" on its name.

Somehow on Firefox, the images terminated with this string are not loading.
I made some test and documented at this [issue](https://github.com/amimaro/stranger-image/issues/1).

Tested with Firefox 59 and 60.

Comment: Have you tried enabling java-script permission for the browser in advance settings of browser, this happen sometime and you need to re enable it.

Comment: Didn't worked..

Comment: Works for me with Firefox 60.0.2 and macOS 10.13.5. Maybe it's related to some extensions you have. Can you try using the [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?

Comment: I tried with Firefox 60.0.1 and Ubuntu 17.10 on safe mode and still didn't worked for me. I asked a friend to try on Windows and it worked fine. Perhaps it's related with Ubuntu...